# Change value of scss variable depending on API response in Vue 3 with Bootstrap

Tags: vue.js, webpack, import, sass, bootstrap-5

I am using Vue 3 and bootstrap 5. I have now override the Bootstrap primary color using a scss file that I import before the bootstrap scss file. Defined in my `config.vue.js`

```
module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: false,
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        additionalData: `
        @import "@/globals/scss/_variables.scss";
        @import "@/globals/scss/_bootstrap-override.scss";
        @import "@/globals/scss/_global.scss";
        @import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
        `,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

When my webapp starts, it does an API request, and in the response there are a color value. I want to use that color as the Bootstrap primary color.

I am now quite lost, is this in any way doable?

Comment: This cannot work because SASS vars are used at compilation time, while you're doing a request at runtime. You can either do a request at build time in Node and provide them to SASS somehow, or stick to CSS vars everywhere.

Comment: using CSS vars is also ok, the only thing is that I don't want to write the variable in every component, but I want to define it once and using it for all components, and that this variable have to override the default primary color of bootstrap. That's actually my problem.

Comment: You can specify `var(--my-var)` in .scss files instead of color values, that's how it can be done in such case. Don't remember if this will work well for Bootstrap, if it uses SASS color transforms like `lighten` then this obviously won't work, and you're limited to another option mentioned above